# String Manipulation with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, r

I'm struggling with another `regex` expression.  I have:

```
test <- "some.a, stuff.b, is.c, here.d, e, f, goaway.g"
"some.a, stuff.b, is.c, here.d, e, f, goaway.g"
```

I want:

```
gsub("??", "", test)
"a, b, c, d, e, f, g"
```

I can't figure out what to put for my pattern.  I tried something like `"*\\.?"` and it didn't work.  I'm no familiar enough with regex to know what I'm doing yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
[a-z]+\.
```

As in, `gsub("[a-z]+\\.", "", test)`.

Comment: Just a small note, in case anyone is curious, I used `[a-z,_]+\\.` to also include underscores.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer You're also including commas, there. You probably mean `[a-z_]`. If you want to include uppercase letters as well, you can use `\w`.